# Is fluoridation practiced in the Palestinian territories?

Tags: palestine, water

Recently, Israel has stopped [fluoridation of water](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Health-Minister-German-outlaws-fluoridation-of-all-tap-water-371332).

Does the Gaza strip or the West Bank have fluoridation of water?

Comment: Im not sure this is really a politics question though.

Comment: "Israel has stopped fluoridation of water"
Have they actually removed it from water yet? I know a group of experts have taken the Health Minister taken to the High Court.
-Dan

Answer (score 4):

> Does the Gaza strip or the West Bank have fluoridation of water?

Looks like the Gaza Strip has high naturally occurring fluoride in it's water. Greater than the suggested beneficial amount of 0.7-1.0ppm.

> "Except for the north area, the average concentration of fluoride in
>   the groundwater in the Gaza Strip is higher than the WHO standards
>   (1.5 mg/l). The most affected areas are Khan Younis (2.7 mg/l) and
>   Rafah (2 mg/l)"

http://www.ewash.org/files/library/Fact%20sheet%203%20-%20Water%20Quality%20in%20the%20Gaza%20Strip.pdf

> "Groundwater from 73 municipal and 21 private wells were analyzed for
>   Ag, Al, As, B, Ba, Cd, Co, Cr, Cu, Fe, Hg, Li, Mn, Ni, Pb, Sr and Zn
>   over a 3 year monitoring program in the Gaza Strip. The results show
>   that the trace elements of the groundwater of the Gaza Strip do not
>   generally pose any health or environmental hazard. In spite of that,
>   only 10% of the municipal wells meet the WHO standards. Cl-, NO 3 −
>   and **F- concentrations exceeded 2–9 times the WHO standards in 90%** of
>   the wells tested with maximum concentrations of 3,000, 450 and 1.6
>   mg/l, respectively. Several private wells should not be used for
>   drinking purposes as the average of Zn, Cd, Pb, Fe and As was 58, 30,
>   270, 468 and 10 μg/l, respectively. A severe water dilemma will appear
>   in the near future from both quality and quantity aspects"

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00254-006-0246-9

> Is fluoridation practiced in the Palestinian territories?

Don't think so. In case someone else finds this link (below), it is talking about the Texas Palestine. 
http://www.palestineherald.com/news/local_news/article_3f608ff4-21c0-5148-b42a-ace74d4a9ce6.html

It isn't listed on "The extend of fluoridation" by the British Fluoridation Society:
http://www.bfsweb.org/onemillion/09%20One%20in%20a%20Million%20-%20The%20Extent%20of%20Fluoridation.pdf

-Dan

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully not, though I wasn't able to find any hard data.

According to [UNICEF "Waterfront" article "Fluoride in water: An overview" about fluorisis](http://www.unicef.org/wash/files/wf13e.pdf) about endemic diseases caused by **naturally occurring overabundance** of fluorides in drinking water, "Palestine" is in the wide blue band of problematic countries stretching from Morocco in the west to China and Japan in the east (this seems to be geographically/geologically clustered, and independent of poverty since the list includes Japan, Australia, Kenya and Bangladesh; but I didn't dig into research as to what the proposed reason for the band are).

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoridation_by_country#Israel suggests that the south of Israel has enough fluoride, which would suggest the Gaza strip has enough.